# Is it possible to add HTML to slot string in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I've made an expander component using Vue.js and I need to line break some of the answers. How would I add the line-break tag properly into the slot string? As of now they naturally show up as a string:

```
<expander identifier="pricing" question="This a question?" answer="This is an answer that really needs a <br/> tag."></expander>
```

Comment: if you design the component=expander by yourself, why not pass `props=answer` whose type is array, then render the answer with the template like `<p v-for="(item, index) in answer" :key="index">`, or if you still like to use string, uses something like `<p v-for="(item, index) in answer.split('<br/>')" :key="index">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply the [`white-space: pre-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) style to the element that you're rendering the answer string into, then you can use newlines in the answer string like this:

```vue
<expander :answer="'This is an answer that really needs a \n tag.'"></expander>
```